# jQuery: $(this) on mouseenter-function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Html:

```
<th>
<div class="relative">
  <span class="colHeader">
    <a class="colHeaderEl" data-index="1" id="extension" value="extension">extension</a>
    <div data-index="1" class="delAll">
      <button data-index="1" class="btn_del">
        <i class="icon-trash"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</th>
```

My JS on th mouseenter:

```
$(this).find('.btn_del').css("display","block"); //doesn´t work?!
```

`// $('.btn_del').css("display","block"); //` <- this works, but than, all my `.btn_del` icons were set to display in my menu - i would like to show only one icon, when i hovered...

// (console.log knows, when I hover - so the function works)

define function:

```
"mouseenter th" : "delMouseEntered",
...

delMouseEntered: function(){
  $(this).find('.btn_del').css("display","block");
},
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show the complete event handler code.

Comment: share the mouseenter event as well

Answer (score 2):

Try binding the `mouseenter` event on the `th`. Then find the button and show it!

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'th', function() {
   $(this).find('.btn_del').css("display","block");
});
```

**Note:**

Bind the event on a parent element. Then find the button and apply the css you want

Comment: so element is not visible in beginning. how would hover event gonna get fired in that case??

Comment: Even after update. This answer isn't valid. What if OP is trying to use mouseenter event from `a` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have attached event handler on anchor as it is the only element with text in group and for binding event to other parent element will work for shared snippet. In that case, you need to target next sibling element of hovered anchor element.

```
$('a.colHeaderEl').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).next().show;
});
```

I believe you will also need to hide the element on mouseout. You can us `.hover()` for this:

```
$('a.colHeaderEl').hover(function() {
  $(this).next().show();
},function() {
  $(this).next().hide();
});;
```

Comment: This answer is probably valid as per OP try.+1 But its just not next but next and child of it.